# NullPointer exception while parsing JSON Map in java

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I'm trying to parse productId, name, and price from my below JSON in the REST API - but I'm getting null pointer exception when I try to get he `name` - `String name = (String) obj.get("name");`, may I know what I'm doing wrong here?

Any help would be really appreciated. 
Thanks!

JSON:

```
{
    "id": "af0b86eb-046c-4400-8bc4-0e26042b8f53",
    "products": [{
            "productId": "1234",
            "name": "apple",
            "price": "383939"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> create(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> obj) {
    Product response = myservice.create(obj);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Service.java

```
public Product create(Map<String, Object> obj) { 
    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : obj.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }       

    Object [] products = (Object[]) obj.get("products");
    HashMap <String, Object> productOne = (HashMap) products[0];
    String productId = (String) productOne.get("name");
    System.out.println("productId: " +productId);

    String name = (String) obj.get("name");
    System.out.println("name: " +name);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Key : products Value : [{productId=1234, name=apple, price=383939}]
```

Comment: It seems you're getting NPE on the `obj` instance, make sure it's correctly wired into your service

Comment: its wired properly, i'm able to print the obj value

Answer (score 5):

By `obj.get("name")`, you try getting value by key `name` from a top-level of your json request, while it's a property of a second-level object

In pseudo-code (skipping casting and null-checks) it should look like this:
`obj.get("products")[0].get("name")`

Comment: oh..How to get second-level object :(

Comment: I tried this approach obj.get("products")[0].get("name") but Java is not liking this kind of syntax

Answer (score 2):

In Service.java you print **obj** inside for loop. Your print says that **key** is **products** and value is an array of objects.

So in following line **obj** is that top-level object and not contains “name” field.

```
String name = (String) obj.get("name");
System.out.println("name: " +name);
```

What if you call `obj.get(“products”)` and try to cast it into a collection? Then trying to fetch the first index from the collection. It should contain the inner object which contains **name** key and value.

Comment: I tried this - Map<String, Object> testobj = (Map<String, Object>) obj.get("products");
System.out.println("value is: " +testobj.get("name"));
but I'm getting this exception Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList incompatible with java.util.Map

Comment: Check @NiVeR answer below.

Comment: I tried but getting same kind of exception - not sure why its not working

Comment: Hard to reproduce the problem myself but look that exception. Looks like object cannot just cast to Map because obj.get("products") seems to return List type.

Comment: So you should cast it into List or ArrayList. 

Are you using some web framework like Spring here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186365/discussion-between-t-nylund-and-learn-groovy).

Answer (score 1):

You should reason exactly as you see the json, by depth(or level).

Initially the whole json is contained in the `obj` map which contains two key-value pairs:

```
(key = "id", value = "af0b86eb-046c-4400-8bc4-0e26042b8f53")
(key = "products", value = [{"productId": "1234", "name": "apple", "price": "383939"}])
```

Since you are interested in product details, the first step is two extract the array `products` like this:

```
Object [] products = obj.get("products");
```

Now product is an array of objects. Since you know that your objects are in turn hash maps you can cast each object to a map and access the key(s) that you want:

```
HashMap <String, Object> productOne = (HashMap) products[0];
String productId = (String) productOne.get("productId");
String name = (String) productOne.get("name");
..
```

Comment: I tried this but getting this exception Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList incompatible with [Ljava.lang.Object; Update the code in original post.